# Laravel do not show me the correct date on the page

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying with laravel 5.3 to create a url like, however, does not show me the correct data

> localhost/game/ID-NameGame-Console

I have tried:

```
public function getGame($slug) {
  $game             = \DB::table('games')->first();
  $info_game = \DB::table('info_games')->where('id_game', '=', $game->id_game)->first();
  $console      = \DB::table('console')->where('id', '=', $info_game->id_console)->first();
  $slug             = $game->id.'-'.$game->slug.'-'.$console->abb_cat;
  return view('front.pages.game', compact('game','info_game','console'));
}
```

The database table is composed in:

```
game
*----------------*
id |  slug 
1  | the-order
5  | uncharted
*----------------*

info_game
*-------------------------*
id | console_id | id_games
1  |      2     | 5
*-------------------------*
```

And so the url become:

localhost/game/5-uncharted-ps4

because console_id 2 = ps4

He shows me the page, however, shows me the game data with ID 1 namely The Order and not Uncharted

---

**Update**

By following the advice given in the comments, I decided to go this route:

web.php

```
Route::get('game/{id}-{slug}-{cons}', 'FrontController@getGame');
```

FrontController.php

public function getGame($id,$slug,$cons) {

```
$game           = \DB::table('games')->where('slug', '=', $slug)->first();
$info_game = \DB::table('info_games')->where('id_game', '=', $game->id)->first();
$console        = \DB::table('console')->where('id', '=', $info_game->id_console)->first();
$id = $game->id;
$cons = $console->abb_cat;
```

But I do not understand why when I try to access the page, it automatically mixes me the data:

> at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Trying to get property of
>   non-object',
>   '\app\Http\Controllers\FrontController.php',
>   40, array('id' => '1', **'slug' => 'the'**, **'cons' => 'order-1886-ps4'**,
>   'game' => null)) in FrontController.php line 40

but instead it had to be:
id: 1
slug: the-order-1886
cons: ps4

Comment: The slug that gets passed in is `5-uncharted-ps4`. You're never using your slug anywhere in your function to get the game, you're just getting the first row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved to:

```
preg_match_all("/([^\-]+)\-(.+)\-(.+)/",$fatSlug,$parts);

$id = $parts[1];
$slug = $parts[2];
$cons = $parts[3];
```

Thanks to Snapey of laracasts

Answer (score 0):

your table `game` has no `id_game` column it has `id` and in `console` there's no `id_console` it's `console_id` so your queries

```
$info_game = \DB::table('info_games')->where('id_game', '=', $game->id_game)->first();
$console   = \DB::table('console')->where('id', '=', $info_game->id_console)->first();
```

should be

```
$info_game = \DB::table('info_games')->where('id_game', '=', $game->id)->first();
$console   = \DB::table('console')->where('id', '=', $info_game->console_id )->first();
```

**And** if you're trying to generate a slug for some game. you've to select it correctly. you're always choosing the first game by `$game = \DB::table('games')->first();` you've to use something like `$game = \DB::table('games')->where('slug' ,'=', $slug)->first();`

Comment: It works, But unfortunately continues to take the game data with id 1 and when I go to retrieve `{{ $game->title }}` in blade.php, he releases "The Order" and not "Uncharted"...

Comment: how your slug form is `ID-NameGame-Console` and the real data is `the-order`

Comment: And so there is no way to create a URL like starting from a slug as `"the-order"`? I tried something like this, though ugly (to be used as a test...) `$link = $gioco->id.'-'.$gioco->slug.'-'.$console->abb_cat;`
Only then, what I put in the "where" of the table game?

Comment: you've many approaches here: 1. is to use a unique slug like`the-order` only without these `id`,`Console` and then you'll use the `where()` as mentioned in the answer. 2.to use a url parameters like `/{id}/{slug}/{slug}` and then in the controller you've to use these parameters as `public function getGame($id, $slug, $console)` and so you've the three variables ready to use. 3. to parse the slug string which I don't recommend

Comment: if you were trying to parse the slug like `ID-NameGame-Console` take care of `NameGame` like `the-order` as it'll give you a slug like `1-the-order-ps4` so you can't explod the string with `-`. instead you've to ensure that the `NameGame` will never have `-`s

Comment: thanks for the help you are giving me, I updated the main message, as you see I have followed your second suggestion, but unfortunately laravel when I visit the melee page data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139893/discussion-between-xanger-and-m-elwan).